# Unable to create database when hosting website on IIS Server. Locally it's working

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, iis-8

I'm unable to create a database when hosting a website on IIS Server. Locally it's working. I just want to execute this procedure via a URL.

```
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.createdb
(
    @cmd varchar(1000),
    @dbname varchar(50)
)
AS
BEGIN
SET NOCOUNT ON;
IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM sys.databases WHERE name = @dbname)
    BEGIN
    SET @cmd=' CREATE database '+ @dbname;
    EXEC (@cmd);
    END
END
```

Comment: Where's the C# code which executes this SQL? What error are you getting? We can only possibly guess what the problem might be (e.g. network access, permissions or something). The query on its own doesn't tell us what the problem is, and the phrase "unable to" doesn't tell us anything useful either. It indicates you maybe haven't investigated the problem fully. Check the actual error, then compare your IIS environment with your local environment to see what differences there are which might be relevant to the specific error.

Comment: What database server are you trying to connect to (Connection String)

Comment: find ode in answer section

Comment: Answers are not for adding info to the question. Unsurprisingly, they're for providing solutions to your problem. Instead please use the "edit" button underneath your question to add further information to it. P.S. you also still haven't told us what error you get.

Answer (score 0):

```
 public void createDB(string _date)
{
    myConnectionString = string.Empty;
    string dbName = _date;
    myConnectionString = "Data Source=localhost; initial catalog=xxxxxxxx;Persist Security Info=True; user id=xxxxxx; password=xxxxxxx; Connection Timeout=7000;";
    using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(myConnectionString.ToString()))
    {
        DataSet ds = new DataSet();
        conn.Open();           
        string sql = string.Empty;
        try
        {
            SqlCommand Cmd = new SqlCommand("createdb", conn);
            Cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            Cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@dbname", dbName);
            Cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            string data = e.Message;
            RecordErrorLog("CreateMyFile¶" + data + "¶" + myConnectionString);
        }
        finally
        {
            if (conn.State != ConnectionState.Closed)
                conn.Close();
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Please do not only paste a code, write some comments and explain how that code works and how it can help